# What is the best way to insert a Thumbnail into a page?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, custom-form, edit-form, image-upload

I have a custom webpart that displays information / fields pages.
I want to create a field for the user insert an image on the page that will be the icon/Thumbnail.

(I need the image to be from the computer and not just a URL as the default fields indicate. I'm not sure how to do this, because the pages have the images of your content saved in another image library.)

I will customize the webpart to display this icon, with other information.

What is the best way to insert icon / image on a page?

Answer (score 0):

You could upload the image to a library by REST API and then reference the image URL in current page.

You could check the sample "Code example 2: Upload a file in the same domain by using the REST API and jQuery" from below thread.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery